# How to extends action in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a problem like this, need your help.
In Symfony framework, i like to create the admin page and i have some page to manage product, category,... And I'd like to check log in before access to those pages.

Admin page have routing like this:  /admin

Add Product: /admin/product/add

Edit Product: /admin/product/edit

Add category: /admin/category/add

Edit category: /admin/category/edit

...

So my question is: How can i check login first for routing above. Of course i can manual add check on each action of them. But Is there any way to check login in one place?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Security configuration and access control: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are no preExcute in Symfony2. So we should use the EventDispacher
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html